# Call of overloaded function ambiguous

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Below is a function which is supposed to locate the string in lookUp in the array prod. It is not doing so.

```
void search(char prods[],char lookUp)
{
    int index = 0;
    char *strPtr = NULL;
        while(index < 5){               
         strPtr = strstr(prods[index], lookUp);
         if (strPtr != NULL)
                 break;
            index++;
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the exact error and which line?

Comment: What test cases did you use? and is prods supposed to be a char array or an array of char pointers?  It looks like from your call to strstr() that it should read strstr(&prods[index], lookup) if it is truly a char [].

Comment: LINE 6the error is call of overloaded str(char& char&) is ambiguous

Comment: And here I was looking for an ambiguous *operator* like the title suggests.

Comment: error messages are sometimes misleading, i was wondering if the problem is the header conflicting with line 6.

Comment: @AvinashJairam, that's why it's important to post the entire error message in your question. We've seen tons of each usually.

Comment: that is the entire error message which i got

Answer (score 1):

```
strPtr = strstr(prods[index], lookUp);
```

strstr() returns a pointer to the first occurrence of     str2(string, not a char) in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1. 
i think     strchr() can do it~~~

Answer (score 1):

If these are truly strings as it states in your question, it should read like this.

```
void search(char *prods[],char *lookUp)
{
    int index = 0;
    char *strPtr = NULL;
    while(index < 5)
    {               
        strPtr = strstr(prods[index], lookUp);
        if (strPtr != NULL)
             break;
        index++;
    }
 }
```